# Mocha-casperjs is not creating the xunit file

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, xunit

I am using [mocha-casperjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-casperjs) for running my tests. I'm running my tests with the command `make test`. Thereby my *Makefile* looks like:

**Makefile:**

```
test:
    # Clear console log before we start.
    @clear

    # Make sure we are not having too much modules.
    @npm prune

    # Make sure we have the required modules.
    @npm install

    # Clear the console, so we only see the test results.
    @clear

    # Run the test.
    ./node_modules/.bin/mocha-casperjs sample.js --xunit=xmllog.xml

.PHONY: test
```

But the *xmllog.xml* is never created. I tried to touch the *xmllog.xml* before running the test. I tried to fore errors in the test, to make sure failing tests are skipped. I have already commented the failing tests. But no *xmllog.xml* is created. Does someone have a clue?

I am running mocha-casperjs version 1.1.0-beta3.

Thanks!

**Answer:**

Thanks to @vanadium23 I was able to solve this way too easy issue. I was confusing the documentation of CasperJS itself and mocha-casperjs. His answer was:

> In documentation there is no such option as --xunit. Instead of this, you need to use option --file=xmllog.xml

Thanks @vanadium23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In documentation there is no such option as --xunit. Instead of this, you need to use option --file=xmllog.xml

Comment: That was actually pretty obvious xD Thanks!